# Check next event before executing handler of previous to hide autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an Angular input field which works like an autocomplete dropdown.

I show the suggestions as input matches existing data. I have to hide the dropdown when focus is lost.

```
<input type="text" 
   ng-model="ctrl.inputs.name"
   ng-blur="ctrl.autocomplete.visible = false"
   ng-keyup="ctrl.handleAutocomplete()"/> <!-- logic for suggestions -->

<div ng-repeat="name in ctrl.names" data-name"{{name.name}}" 
   ng-click="ctrl.setName($event)">
    {{name.name}}
</div>
```

Now while typing inputs, this works fine and I get a list of items.
Ideally, you click on an item from the list to set it in controller. I am already hiding the suggestions in controller at that point - `ctrl.autocomplete.visible = false`.

But before the `ng-click` of the options, `ng-blur` is called on input, which hides the dropdown list. So I never reach to `ng-click`. Removing the `ng-blur` works fine, but I need to hide the dropdown when focus is lost from input.
Help Appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could stop ng-blur from hiding the div if the mouse is over the div-element. That way you will not hide the div when the user tries to select a result. Another approach is to use a third-party library which has implemented the typeahead functionality for you: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: gave up. Using `ui.bootstrap` now.

Answer (score 1):

remove

```
ng-blur="ctrl.autocomplete.visible = false"
```

from

```
<input type="text" 
   ng-model="ctrl.inputs.name"
   ng-blur="ctrl.autocomplete.visible = false"
   ng-keyup="ctrl.handleAutocomplete()"/>
```

and set

```
ctrl.autocomplete.visible = false;
```

at last of `ctrl.setName($event)` method in controller file.

Comment: Would this work if they choose not to use the `autocomplete` list?

Comment: I am already doing this. This just achieves hiding when something has been chosen. Not when focus is lost, like you press tab, click elsewhere, etc.

Comment: @Malkus, yup, that's another problem, I need to take it as new input. Which woks fine for me (implemented)

Answer (score 0):

So I expanded on a directive I have seen before and this should work.

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/a5cndz39/)

**Directive**

```
var blurFocusDirective = function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) {
                return;
            }
            elm.on('focus', function () {
                elm.addClass('has-focus');

                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.hasFocus = true;
                });
            });
            elm.on('blur', function () {
                $timeout(function() {
                    elm.removeClass('has-focus');
                    elm.addClass('has-visited');                        
                }, 250);

            });

        }
    };
};

app.directive('input', blurFocusDirective)
app.directive('select', blurFocusDirective);
```

This directive is bound to allowed `inputs` and `select` fields.  It adds a class to all input fields `has-focus` when then have focus and a class `has-visited` to all fields that have been visited (*you could use `has-visited` for custom validation or something if you wanted*).

I added a short `$timeout` to the `blur` event so that the sibling element can be clicked on before it disappears (*otherwise the directive works so fast you can't click the autocomplete options*).

**HTML**

The input fields with `ng-model` will automatically have the classes added.  In order to have a `css` selector grab the sibling I wrapped the `ng-repeat` in a `div`.

```
<input type="text" 
   ng-model="ctrl.inputs.name"
   ng-keyup="ctrl.handleAutocomplete()"/>
<div class="autoComplete">
    <div ng-repeat="name in ctrl.names" data-name"{{name.name}}" 
         ng-click="ctrl.setName($event)">
            {{name.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

The following `css` rule hides the `autoComplete` sections by default.  But if a sibling has `has-focus` the `autoComplete` `div` is displayed.

```
.autoComplete { 
    color:#00F; 
    display:none; }
.has-focus + .autoComplete { 
    display:inline; }
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Malkus/a5cndz39/)